# Unwanted blank page to report class document

Tags: titles, blank-page

I'm using the report class to write a lab report(go figure). In the template used, for some reason I am getting an extra blank page before the title page. What follows is the structure used for the title page.

```
\begin{document}
\frontmatter


\title{ \normalsize \textsc{} \\ \textsc{} \\ \textsc{} \\ \textsc{} \normalsize
    \\ [2.0cm]
    \HRule{0.5pt} \\
    \LARGE \textbf{\uppercase{Impact Lab}}
    \HRule{2pt} \\ [0.5cm]
    \normalsize \vspace*{5\baselineskip}}

\author{ \textbf{}\\
     \\ 
     \\
     \\}


\maketitle
```

My import statements are:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[myheadings]{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig, subcaption, setspace, booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion=true]{microtype}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{url, lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

Any ideas why I'm getting the empty page at the beginning? (Also all text has been removed, that's why the empty braces)

Comment: Call `\frontmatter` after `\maketitle` if that doesn't help additionally `\title` and `\author` in the preamble.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Also note that you are misusing the `\title` and the `\author` macro, imho. If the resulting titlepage isn't to your liking, you can build your own using `\begin{titlepage}...\end{titlepage}`.

Comment: @Skillmon Thank you! Doing that and doing some copy pasta I got my desired result.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280

Comment: @Skillmon Do you want to add an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question's code snippets are far from compilable, the following are just some side notes (in which I combine my comments into an answer).

You should call `\title` and `\author` in the preamble. If that doesn't fix the issue additionally put `\frontmatter` after `\maketitle`.

Note however that the macros `\title` and `\author` are just to store the name of the author and the title. They are not meant to contain formatting switches. If you're not satisfied with the resulting title page, you should use the `titlepage`-environment to typeset your own title page. Note that you shouldn't include the command `\maketitle` in that environment.

Comment: +1 another  questioin off the unanswered list. Do you mean side note?

Comment: @Johannes_B Whoops. Thx for spotting the typo :)